# SvelteKit - npm run build - how to run the application for production? (Dockerized, if possible)

Tags: docker, svelte, sveltekit

I built a Svelte app with Sveltekit. After running `npm run build`, I get a `.svelte-kit` folder with different folders. There is an output folder with subfolders called client and server, which might be promising. I also try to Dockerize my app.

I am able to run `npm run preview`, but this seems not to be suited for production. What is the way to actually run my svelte application? I have seen in other repos, where the app is run with the following command: `CMD ["node", "build/index.js"]`

I currently have this:

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./frontend/package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY ./frontend .

RUN npm run build


FROM node:18-alpine
RUN mkdir /app

COPY --from=builder /app/package.json .
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/.svelte-kit/output ./output

EXPOSE 5577

# See if increase libuv thread pool size makes performance better
# The default value 4
# http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/threadpool.html
ENV UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=32

CMD ["node", "/output/server/index.js"]
```

The command itself works, but running the index.js file just runs through with no error.

How do I actually run my app after creating the production build?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should read the [documentation on adapters](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters) first.

Comment: @H.B.: Thanks, using the node adpter made it work